# Слияние цвета при наложении областей на Яндекс Картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На гугл картах можно сделать чтобы при наложении цветов друг на друга они становились одной областью - так синие круги сливаются с синими, а оранжевые с оранжевыми:

[image: пример из гугл]

Есть ли у API яндекс карт что-то подобное?

Comment: Привет, можно пример кода реализации данной фичи для API гугл карт?

Comment: к сожалению не имеем такого, используем Яндекс, случайно заметил такую тему и стал искать

Comment: Для аналогичного более позднего вопроса такое решение было собрано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1139933/386299

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации такого функционала можно склеить полигоны (операция union) при помощи специализированной библиотеки (к примеру turf.js). Вот пример который иллюстрирует вышесказанное:

```
let union = (circle1, circle2) => {
  let options = {steps: 100, units: 'kilometers', properties: {foo: 'bar'}};
  console.log(circle1.geometry.getCoordinates(), circle1.geometry.getRadius());
  let poly1 = turf.circle(circle1.geometry.getCoordinates(), circle1.geometry.getRadius() / 1000, options);
  let poly2 = turf.circle(circle2.geometry.getCoordinates(), circle2.geometry.getRadius() / 1000, options);
  let union = turf.union(poly1, poly2);
  return new ymaps.Polygon(union.geometry.coordinates);
};

ymaps.ready(function () {
    let myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            // используется перевернутый порядок координат (longlat)
            center: [37.573856, 55.751574],
            zoom: 7
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

    let circle1 = new ymaps.Circle([[37.573856, 55.351574], 50*1000]);
    let circle2 = new ymaps.Circle([[37.673856, 55.851574], 50*1000]);

    let result = union(circle1, circle2);

    myMap.geoObjects.add(result);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4szo31d/5/