# Объединение прозрачных объектов при наложении и полное экранирование одних другими

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Вывожу на карту много меток, использую геометрию метки круг (Circle).   Метки имеют прозрачность. При пересечение нескольких меток они наслаиваются друг на друга, в какой-то момент становятся совсем непрозрачными.

Метки выводятся из json представления с помощью geoQuery (ObjectManager по некоторым причинам использовать не могу).

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при пересечении метки не наслаивались, а как бы сливались друг с другом, если они одного цвета. Но у меня метки разного цвета и в случае пересечения меток разного цвета нужно, чтобы один цвет перекрывал другой (например есть синяя и красная метка и чтобы та часть красной, которая пересекается с синей была не видна вообще, видна только синняя, а остальная часть красной, которая ни с чем не пересекается была видна).

Идеальный пример того как мне нужно:  https://geo.minsvyaz.ru

Подскажите как такое реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно как в идеальном примере, потребуется:

1. Добавить подвижный полупрозрачный [пейн](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/pane.MovablePane-docpage/) чуть выше 'areas'.
2. Добавлять все круги строго непрозрачными на созданный пейн, с нулевой обводкой, с  необходимым параметром zIndex.

Тогда перекрываться они будут друг другом полностью, а уже результирующий слой будет прозрачным.

Если после потребуется прозрачное наложение, можно будет добавить дополнительный такой пейн и распределять объекты по созданным пейнам.

```
var newPane = new ymaps.pane.MovablePane(myMap, {zIndex: 210, overflow: 'hidden', css:{opacity: 0.5}});
myMap.panes.append("circlePane", newPane);

myMap.geoObjects.options.set({'fillOpacity': 3, 'strokeWidth': 0, 'pane': 'circlePane'});

var myCircle1 = new ymaps.Circle([[55.76, 37.60], 10000], {}, {
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    zIndex: 1
}),
myCircle2 = new ymaps.Circle([[55.76, 37.80], 10000], {}, {
    fillColor: "#0000FF",
    zIndex: 0
});

myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle1).add(myCircle2);
```

Реализация на jsbin: https://jsbin.com/kofuwoc/edit?js,output

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы метки были прозрачными и оставались такими же прозрачными при пересечении

Comment: Это реализуемо в полупрозрачном пейне. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Вот это кажется то, что нужно. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Опечатка как-то в пример закралась. Конечно MovablePane, а не StaticPane должен был быть.