# Объединение фигур (многоугольников) в одну

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Можно ли с помощью api Яндекс карт объединить несколько многоугольников в один таким образом, чтобы в случае их наложения друг на друга их фоны не смешивались, а имели один цвет?
Нашел что-то, как мне показалось, подходящее - https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/shape.MultiPolygon-docpage/, но не смог разобраться.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужны именно многоугольники, то можно просто стоить мультиполигоны, добавляя координаты новых полигонов через запятую. Чтобы они не вырезались друг из друга, включите опцию **fillRule: "nonZero"** для геометрии. Это есть в песочнице Яндекса: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon

```
var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
            [
                [55.8, 37.7],
                [55.8, 37.9],
                [55.7, 37.9],
                [55.7, 37.7]
            ],
            [
                [55.73, 37.82],
                [55.73, 37.98],
                [55.63, 37.90]
            ],
            [
                [55.85, 37.75],
                [55.85, 37.95],
                [55.75, 37.95],
                [55.75, 37.75]
            ],
            [
                [55.83, 37.72],
                [55.83, 37.88],
                [55.73, 37.80]
            ]
        ],
        fillRule: "nonZero"
    }}, {
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    opacity: 0.5
});

myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
```

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/uof6mc3e/8/

Если же вам нужно только визуально склеивать геообъекты, то можно использовать полупрозрачный пейн с непрозрачными элементами на нём, как я описывал ранее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1139933/386299